# Create a small file in RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, ramdisk

I know there exists several [RAM disk programs](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/04/03/the-best-free-ramdisk-programs-for-windows/), that allow to create a whole (temporary) filesystem in RAM, but here I have a slightly different request:

How to create a single file in RAM (just a few KB or MB), such that:

- any software, like `notepad.exe`, can open it like this: `notepad.exe c:\ramfolder\test.txt`
- with the Windows built-in tools (or with Python), but no other third-party software?

Comment: Applications use the regular file system, so you need to create a small RAM  disk and give it a drive letter so the applications can use it

Comment: In linux that's possible easily, but in windows you need third party toolkit.  I suggest you using lmDisk toolkit.
It's a tool kit to mount a part of ram or image file as normal disk. you can copy your project (or just your db) there.
I've try it to process raw data and create a db for a game ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. In order to place a file in RAM that does not exist on a local disk but can be accessed by other programs, you need to have a filesystem inside the RAM.

This means you need a RAMDrive. Given that Windows 7 can't natively create one without external tools, you need third-party software.

You should ask yourself why you need this. Is it speed or security? If it is speed, then you have to understand that a file of a few KB or MB will will not be that much slower than RAM. When you open the file from disk, it will be copied to RAM and then executed, its just that another program that wants to access this file will also do the same, giving you more copies of the program. That said, were you to use a RAM drive and open the file, it would still make a copy of the program from RAM to RAM anyway.

If it is security, you should note that a filesystem is more secure than RAM anyway. The reason is that everytime you setup the RAM drive and copy the files there, you have to undergo quite a procedure which can be analysed and traced more easily than if the file is stored with security in place on the harddisk itself.

One last reason I can think of that you want to accomplish, is that you need to stop the user from accessing files on the C drive and so your goal is to hide the C drive and have the program they use accessible by other means. If this is indeed the goal, you will want to give the user limited rights and set security permissions on the C drive accordingly. This way, they can still see the C drive, but they can't do much unless a user with sufficient rights is logged in.

So long answer short, it is not possible, but it is likely not going to be the solution you are after anyway.

Comment: It was for security reasons indeed. Long story cut short: I wanted to be able to open an encrypted file on disk, decrypt to to RAM with a password (example: `Z:\plaintext.txt`), be able to edit this with my favorite text editor (example: Sublime Text), save (to the RAM file, so **no unencrypted data will be stored on hardware disk!**), then encrypt this RAM file and save the file, encrypted, to disk.

Comment: 2/2 Of course I could do this with 7zip + a python script, but then the unencrypted data would still be written on disk (and thus, it could be undeleted!), even if it's only as a temporary file... I could also do it with an extra Bitlocker disk `Z:` of 100 MB on my hard drive. But then the UI/UX would not be perfect: I would like that when I close the `.txt` file in my text editor, it is automatically encrypted, and if I close the editor, the access should be removed, **until I type the password again**. This wouldn't work with Bitlocker (i.e. auto-lock the device when I close a txt file).

Comment: Okay, its possible, but you will need a third-party ram disk tool. Note, there are portable programs, I'm sure there must be a portable ramdisk tool too. You  should try portablefreeware.com and see if they have something.

Comment: @Basj I think the problem with that idea is that not all text editors actually keep a permanent open handle to the file -- some of them close the file immediately after loading into memory, then reopen when they need to save. So if you relied entirely on a filesystem-based implementation (which locks as soon as all handles are closed), you wouldn't be able to save any changes to the file.

Comment: So you basically have to rig something external which would lock the volume when the whole program exited (but that creates its own problems: what happens if the program never exits because it's emacs or vscode or some other mega-editor that you use all day long?)